# Calendar overlays in not visible on front page

Tags: 2013, list, calendar, app, sharepoint-calendar

I created a new Calendar APP `global_calendar`, where I want to view all my other calendars. Then I added multiple overlays and checked "Always show".

In the default Calendar overview of `global_calendar` (when I just click on it in the menu left), everything works fine.

But when I put `general_calendar` as an App Part to my front page, either in default view (calendar) or as List View, I just see the `general_calendar`, without the overlays.

How to enable the overlays in both, default calendar view on the front page and in List View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the OverLays to the Home Page App Part.

OverLays you set for one Calendar part will not get copied over.

Comment: I didn't find any option for that, when editing the App Part. Can you please tell me, where to look for that?

Comment: Yes. You can edit the page, then edit webpart. Then you can see the Ribbon -> Calendar -> Calendar Overlays